# jQuery Mobile button click event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, events, jquery-mobile

I'm new to JQuery Mobile so excuse me for this probably easy question.

I have a button:

```
<a id="btnSort" href=# data-role="button"
                runat="server" onclick="Click_btnSort">Sort</a>
```

and code-behind event handler:

```
protected void Click_btnSort(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ...
        }
```

I've got a breakpoint at the beginning of this method, however it does not fire when I click on the button.

PS. I'm not using any field validators.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello. Sorry, but this "protected void Click_btnSort(object sender, EventArgs e)" isn't JavaScript. What do you want to run?

Comment: `<a id="btnSort" href=# data-role="button" onclick="Click_btnSort()">Sort</a>`

By the way , is your method definition in JavaScript?

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa that is ASP.NET and C#.

Comment: The method is from the page's code-behind isn't JavaScript. I'm expecting that because I've used runat="server" I'll be able to handle the event with the c# code-behind. Am I wrong here?

Comment: have you tried adding a listener `$(document).on('click', '#btnSort', function () { Click_btnSort(); }); `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your event is nog firing is because you use a html a-element, that element does not trigger a postback (maybe it does when you set the elements autopostback proerty to true, not sure if this works for a-elements).

When you want to use the ASP.NET button click event in code behind (to do server side stuff when clicking), you probably better use a ASP:Button or LinkButton element, which works out of the box.

When you want to use a client side click event (for example with jQuery, to do client side stuff when clicking), you probably better add an event listener to the  element like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSort', function () {
 // client side stuff here
});
```

EDIT:

See this for basic client side event binding with jQuery. If this does not look familiar, please read about JavaScript / jQuery basics, it will be worth the time

http://jsfiddle.net/6mYQN/1/

Answer (score 1):

As `<a>` tag is not related to serverside controls so I suppose that can't happen like that way.

your code even with run at server is still will look for the `Click_btnSort` in javascript function no the one in code behind so you should add a function in script/javascript tag with the name you will call in `onclick` event.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old post what you can do is create a

```
<asp:Button ID="btnServerSort" style="display:none;"  runat="server" Text="SORT" OnCommand="Click_btnServerSort" ..>
```

with an associated server side  event.

Then modify the code as follow

```
<a id="btnSort" href=# data-role="button" data-ajax="false" runat="server"  onserverclick="Click_btnServerSort"   >Sort</a>
```

I hope this helps.